# Terraform - Building an Output Map

Tags: terraform

I want to see if I can build an output map that would include all properties of an Azure Resource Group. The first two outputs I created work just fine, but is there a way to create one map structure that outputs all of them into one structure?

For example, one map that shows Resource Group Name, location, tags?

**Variable Definition**

```
variable "resource_groups" {
  description = "Resource groups"
  type = map(object({
    name     = string
    location = string
    tags     = map(string)
  }))
}
```

**Main**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_groups" {
  for_each = var.resource_groups # name of RG is unique
  name     = each.value["name"]
  location = each.value["location"]
  tags     = each.value["tags"]
}
```

**Outputs**

```
###Resource Group Outputs###
output "resource_group_ids_map" {
  value       = { for r in azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups : r.name => r.id }
  description = "A map of resource group IDs."
}

output "resource_group_tags_map" {
  value       = { for r in azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups : r.name => r.tags }
  description = "A map of resource group tags"
}
```

After playing around with this I believe I have the answer. New Code below.

```
output "resource_group_map" {
  value = {
    for rg in azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups :
    rg.name => ({
      id       = rg.id
      location = rg.location
      tags     = rg.tags
    })

  }
  description = "A map of all resource group values."
}
```

Comment: "I am a bit lost if that is correct" is not specific. What's exactly wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: I updated my initial ask. I have note run the code because I know it is wrong. Is there a way to output a map for all resource group values (name,location,tags) into one structure? I have defined individual ones (the first two outputs) but I want to really create one structure that outputs all.

Comment: What is the definition of `azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups`?

Comment: After some attempts, I believe I have found the solution. Interested to hear back on any comments about this approach. Thank you. New code posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I came up with to output all the properties of resource groups in one structure using a for loop.

```
output "resource_group_map" {
  value = {
    for rg in azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups :
    rg.name => ({
      id       = rg.id
      location = rg.location
      tags     = rg.tags
    })

  }
  description = "A map of all resource group values."
}
```